# Why this error occurs in jdk 1.7 in Red hat Linux?

Tags: java, linux

Why this error occurs in jdk 1.7 in Red hat Linux ?

```
java -jar app.jar
```

---

```
Error: dl failure on line 863
Error: failed /java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so,
because /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' 
not found (required by /java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so)
```

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/lib-tls-libc-so-6-version-%60glibc_2-4'-not-found-error-when-invoking-java-y-917384/

Comment: How did you install Java? Seems not all dependencies are there.

Comment: Thanks all of you my Red Hat linux version is 2.6.9 unspported jdk1.7.

Comment: Why are you using JDK 7? Also, you are missing C/C++ libraries. Check out how to install those with yum. Also, red-hat is more of a server platform rather than a developer platform. Go for Fedora if you require that.